# UPDATE Table value from other table like distribution

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a `table 1` where I have to distribute award from other table `table 2` but in a manner of First in first serve from other table row.

```
Table 1
ATTIME    | Absent | LeaveType
-----------------------------
2019-01-01| 1      | 
2019-01-02| 1      | 
2019-01-03| 1      | 
2019-01-04| 1      | 
2019-01-05| 1      | 
2019-01-06| 1      | 

Table 2
LeaveType | Total  
-------------------
Casual    | 3   
Sick      | 2
```

I have achieved it by using cursor, but want a set base **UPDATE QUERY**  or any other option which optimize my execution plan,

Final Result will be....

```
Table 1

ATTIME    | Absent | LeaveType
-----------------------------
2019-01-01| 1      | CL
2019-01-02| 1      | CL
2019-01-03| 1      | CL
2019-01-04| 1      | SL
2019-01-05| 1      | SL
2019-01-06| 1      |
```

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server.

Comment: this is the only licence source that i have available here

Answer (score 0):

In a supported version of SQL Server, you would use a cumulative sum and `row_number()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t1.*,
             row_number() over (order by attime) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     )
update toupdate
    set leavetype = t2.leavetype
    from (select t2.*,
                 sum(total) over (order by leavetype) as runningtotal
          from table2 t2
         ) t2
    where toupdate.seqnum between t2.runningtotal + 1 - total and t2.runningtotal;
```

In archaic, unsupported versions of SQL Server, the cumulative sum is more cumbersome.  One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t1.*,
             row_number() over (order by attime) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     )
update toupdate
    set leavetype = t2.leavetype
    from (select t2.*,
                 (select sum(total)
                  from table2 tt2
                  where tt2.leavetype <= t2.leavetype
                ) as runningtotal
          from table2 t2
         ) t2
    where t1.seqnum between t2.runningtotal + 1 - total and t2.runningtotal;
```

Comment: The multi-part identifier "t1.seqnum" could not be bound

Comment: for upgraded version, please tell me the solution?